# SQL Server localDB could not create file

Tags: c#, sql-server, localdb

i am trying to recreate this sample
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/

I did everything according to the text, the program compiles fine, but then it fails creating the database
It seems like the db file 
*'C:\Users\WolfgangConsoleApp4.BlogContext.mdf'* is missing a \ after Wolfgang. 
But I do not know where to enter the path correctly. 
On the laptop in my company I could rebuild and run the sample code without errors.

this is the complete exception text:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
HResult=0x80131904
Nachricht = CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Zugriff verweigert) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Users\WolfgangConsoleApp4.BlogContext.mdf'.
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
Quelle = .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Stapelüberwachung:
bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c.<NonQuery>b__4_0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
bei System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass52_0.<CreateDatabaseFromScript>b__0(DbConnection conn)
bei System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass60_0.<UsingConnection>b__0()
bei System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Execute>b__0()
bei System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
bei System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
bei System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
bei System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
bei System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript)
bei System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
bei System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
bei System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
bei System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
bei System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
bei System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass66_0`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__0()
bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<>c.<InitializeDatabase>b__58_0(InternalContext c)
bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
bei System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
bei ConsoleApp4.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Wolfgang\source\repos\ConsoleApp4\ConsoleApp4\Program.cs: Zeile29
```

Maybe my VS Community Edition does not allow this?
Or maybe I have too many versions of sql server and localdb and so installed?
Greetings 
Wolfgang

Comment: You need to patch your localdb install, it is a know issue with LocaldDB 2017. Our use 2019 - https://medium.com/cloudnimble/upgrade-visual-studio-2019s-localdb-to-sql-2019-da9da71c8ed6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ErikEJ posted in a comment, I have to update my localdb install.
For this i used [Cumulative Update 6 for SQL Server 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4101464/cumulative-update-6-for-sql-server-2017). 
After a restart of the pc it worked.

But code first migrations were not what i initially was searching for... 
I think, I will have to post a new question...